# How to properly get form data with JQuery and formData

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload some form data using ajax and php but for some reason my data is not being catch or passed.

Here is what I have:

form.html ( basic form with 3 text inputs and 1 file)

```
<form class="form" id="superform" action="nada.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tituloQuiz">Resultado:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control resultado" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Ex: Paris">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="desc">Descrição do Site:</label>
              <textarea  class="form-control" id="desc" name="descricao" placeholder="Ex:"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="desc">OG FB DESC:</label>
              <textarea  class="form-control" id="facedes" name="descricao" placeholder="facebook description"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="imggrande">Imagem</label>
            <input type="file" id="imggrande" name="imgres">
            <p class="help-block">Imagem usada na página de resultado e Facebook 600 x 400.</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg addres">Adicionar Resultado</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Próxima Etapa</button>
       </form>
```

And here is the JS that makes the ajax call:
**myjs.js**

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
     $('.row').on('click','.addres',function(){
         console.log('Click Detectado');
         var formulario = $('#superform');
         var formData = new FormData(formulario);

          $.ajax({

                  type: "POST",
                  url: "addres.php",
                  data: formData,
                  async: false,
                  success: function(data) {
                        console.log('Funcionou');
                  },
                  error: function(data) {
                      console.log('Erro no formulario');
                  },
                  cache: false,
                  contetType: false,
                  processData: false
          });


     });
 });
```

Nothing is being passed and the POST call is empty (See screenshots below).
[image: Empty Post]
[image]

```
**addres.php**
<?php
   var_dump($_FILES);
   var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'address.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData($('#superform')[0]), // The form with the file    inputs.
    processData: false,                          // Using FormData, no need to process data.
    contentType:false
  }).done(function(){
     console.log("Success: Files sent!");
  }).fail(function(){
     console.log("An error occurred, the files couldn't be sent!");
});
```

When one sets the contentType option to false, it forces jQuery not to add a Content-Type header, otherwise, the boundary string will be missing from it. Also, when submitting files via multi-part/form one must leave the processData flag set to false, otherwise, jQuery will try to convert your FormData into a string, which will fail.

read from php using

```
 $_FILES['file-0']
```

(There is only one file, file-0, unless you specified the multiple attribute on your file input, in which case, the numbers will increment with each file.)

**Additional info:**
See for yourself the difference of how your formData is passed to your php page by using console.log().

```
    var formData = new FormData($('#superform')[0]);
    console.log(formData);

    var formDataSerialized = $('#superform').serialize();
    console.log(formDataSerialized);
```

Hope this helps.

extra information read this [upload files asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

**Note** : formData doesn't work in IE 9

Comment: Thanks iceburg, now the data is being passed, but the $_FILES is empty. Any on how i access the data on the php side, normally i would use $_POST['titulo'] for example, but this is not working.

Comment: are you getting the file name. try with edited version.

Comment: Yes, but is in the var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @Iceburg: You sure that `contentType:false` is a good idea here? According to docs it makes jQuery send no `Content-Type` header at all, but a file upload would required `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @CBroe contentType option to false is used for multipart/form-data forms that pass files.

When one sets the contentType option to false, it forces jQuery not to add a Content-Type header, otherwise, the boundary string will be missing from it. Also, when submitting files via multi-part/form one must leave the processData flag set to false, otherwise, jQuery will try to convert your FormData into a string, which will fail. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795449/jquery-ajax-form-submission-enctype-multipart-form-data-why-does-contentt

Comment: @André: Thanks, I wasn’t aware of that. Have you re-checked in developer tools to see what does actually get send now? Does that look o.k., compared to what you would get when the form is send “normally”, without AJAX?

Comment: @André: I konw it's an old post but i am still hoping to get an answer. Why do we have to select an index;i.e; 
`new FormData($('#superform')[0])` with an ID selector while creating FormData object whereas an ID selector returns only one object provided that ID has been used only once?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .serializeArray() to get the data in array format and then convert it into an object. like this:

```
    function getFormData(formId) {
       let formData = {};
       let inputs = $('#'+formId).serializeArray();
       $.each(inputs, function (i, input) {
          formData[input.name] = input.value;
      });
      return formData;
   }
```