# Why the change in input type=file is not identified with `form.serialzie()`

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-serialize

I am checking whether the values in `form` has been changed before submitting for updation. All other controls inside `form`, if changed, are identified but
not `input type=file` control. Below is the sample I was trying and if you try submitting `form` with or without uploading file, the response is its **not changed**. Why this behavior with only `input type=file`? Why the change in `input type=file` is not identified?

```js
var form_serialize = "";
$(function() {
  form_serialize = $("#frmProfile").serialize();
})

$('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var isChanged = $("#frmProfile").serialize() == form_serialize ? false : true;
  if (isChanged)
    $('body').append('changed');
  else
    $('body').append('Not changed');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmProfile">
  <input type="file" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: As per the documentation of [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)  : `Data from file select elements is not serialized.`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Any idea how I can overcome this?

Comment: You can use ajaxForm submission plugin on here : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ , which may help you

Comment: Oh.. Ok.. Thank you.. Could you please post it as answer? @PranavCBalan..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of **[serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)**

> Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Instead you can use jQuery **[ajaxForm plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)** which support.

Or you can use `FormData` object , Refer these questions : [Jquery/Ajax Form Submission (enctype="multipart/form-data" ). Why does 'contentType:False' cause undefined index in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795449/jquery-ajax-form-submission-enctype-multipart-form-data-why-does-contentt) , [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)