# Ajax Post and CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to echo back code I received from Ajax. But it does not work when I am using contentType:false, processData:false.

Here is my ajax. The url is correct. If I comment out the line with post_data['file'] and contentType:false, processData:false I will be able to get the echo, but as soon as contentType:false, processData:false is in I cannot get anything.

```
    post_data = {};
    post_data['file']= document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    post_data['paper-type']=$("#paper-input :selected").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/admin/upload_paper',
        data: post_data,
        type: 'post',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data+"error");
        }
    });
```

Here is the code snippet from CI

```
public function upload_paper(){       

    echo $this->input->post('paper-type');
    echo "testing";
    echo "testing2";

}
```

Does anyone know what that is? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you setting __content-type__ to _false_

Comment: console prints "testingtesting2"
I am setting contentType to false because I hope to upload a file later. And in order to upload a file I have to set the contentType and ProcessData to false.

Comment: you should use a `FormData` Object for this

Comment: print_r($_POST) to see if you are getting anything

Comment: try like this:  `url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>/admin/upload_paper',`

Comment: Hi Alex, print_r($_POST) just gives
Array
(
).
I tried using FormData and the new url but the return is the same. When I attempted to perform the upload through either post_data or FormData I receive the error "you did not select a file to upload."

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this:

```
post_data['paper-type']=$("#paper-input :selected").val();
```

try

```
var val = $("#paper-input :selected").val();
```

and in ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/admin/upload_paper',
    data: {'paper-type':val},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data+"error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Kamote, thank you for your help. It does work, but it stops working when I add in the contentType:false and processData:false. And I need those in order to upload a file later.

Comment: try looking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795449/jquery-ajax-form-submission-enctype-multipart-form-data-why-does-contentt