# Handling two echo responses with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do you handle two echo responses from your PHP script with $.ajax() function.Im new to ajax and my code is not working.Here's my code:
form.js

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var Form = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "uploader.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: Form,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data[0]);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

And my uploader.php:

```
echo "stuff1";
//some other code.
echo "stuff2";
```

Wasn't is supposed to alert "stuff1"?...instead it doesn't send the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery/Ajax Form Submission (enctype="multipart/form-data" ). Why does 'contentType:False' cause undefined index in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795449/jquery-ajax-form-submission-enctype-multipart-form-data-why-does-contentt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing the plain text for results you should use JSON for response. And then on server side, you can use arrays to send multiple values in response.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "uploader.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: Form,
    dataType: "json", // <-- Add this param
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data[0]);
    }
});
```

and On php's end, you can use `json_encode()` to convert the array to a `json` string.

```
$output = [];
$output[] = "stuff1";
//some other code.
$output[] = "stuff2";
echo json_encode($output);
```